# use of "along" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "along" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The interaction between leakage flow and suction surface is
>   substantially reduced by optimizing the blade thickness **along** the
>   height of blade in proposed design.

Comment: We can't proofread and suggest improvements. If you have a replacement for _achieved_ in mind, use the [edit] key to add that to your question and ask specifically about it.

Comment: P. E. Dant, I think that above sentences are not good. I correct as follows:

The interaction between leakage flow and suction surface is substantially reduced by optimizing the blade thickness along the height of blade in proposed design. Is it OK?
Thanks,

Comment: Use the [edit] link to **add to your question** and ask a **specific question** about a word or usage. Without that change, the question requires proofreading, which is off-topic here.

Comment: No: your corrected sentence still has deficiencies that have nothing to do with the preposition, although it is used appropriately.